# Сжимает контейнер

Tags: flexbox

Если в контейнере 3 елемента то это сжимаеться в такой вид:
[image: сжатое]

Если добавить еще пару карточек то растягиваеться как надо на всю шиниру контейнера:
[image: норм]

код:

```css
.menu-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 32px;
}

.menu-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 20px;
}

.menu-item {
  flex-basis: calc((100% - 40px) / 3);
  border: none;
  padding: 24px;
}

.menu-card {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  height: 444px;
  padding: 24px;
  background-image: linear-gradient( 180deg, rgba(49, 38, 26, 0) 55.21%, rgba(49, 38, 26, 0.71) 72.92%, var(--color-dark) 100%);
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  border-radius: 16px;
  transition: transform 0.3s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu-card:hover {
  transform: scale(1.05);
}

.menu-image {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 16px;
}

.menus-title {
  margin-bottom: 80px;
}

.menu-title {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: var(--color-light);
}

.menu-text {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: left;
  color: var(--color-light);
}

.carousel-button {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 44px;
  height: 44px;
  padding: 0;
  fill: var(--color-dark);
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid var(--color-dark);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.carousel-button:hover {
  background-color: var(--color-dark);
  fill: var(--color-light);
}

.carousel-button.next {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<section class="section" id="menu-section">
  <div class="container">
    <h2 class="menus-title section-title centered">Меню</h2>
    <div class="menu-container">
      <button class="carousel-button" type="button">
             <svg width="16" height="16">
              <use href="/images/icon.svg#icon-Arrow-1"></use>
            </svg>
          </button>
      <ul class="menu-list">
        <li class="menu-item">
          <article class="menu-card">
            <img class="menu-image" src="./images/menu-pizza.jpg" alt="Pizza">
            <h3 class="menu-title">Pizza</h3>
            <div class="menu-text">
              <p>Pizza - 30 сантиметрів</p>
              <p>Міні-піца на перекус для одного</p>
              <p>Найкращі начинки. Сирні борти</p>
            </div>
          </article>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item">
          <article class="menu-card">
            <img class="menu-image" src="./images/menu-salad.jpg" alt="Салати">
            <h3 class="menu-title">Салати</h3>
            <div class="menu-text">
              <p>Всі улюбленні салати</p>
              <p>Найсмачніша заправка</p>
              <p>Візьми з собою</p>
            </div>
          </article>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item">
          <article class="menu-card">
            <img class="menu-image" src="./images/menu-backery.jpg" alt="Випічка">
            <h3 class="menu-title">Випічка</h3>
            <div class="menu-text">
              <p>Хачапурі</p>
              <p>Сосиска в тісті</p>
              <p>Кальцоне</p>
            </div>
          </article>
      </ul>
      <button class="carousel-button next" type="button">
             <svg width="16" height="16">
              <use href="/images/icon.svg#icon-Arrow-1"></use>
            </svg>
          </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

в чем проблема?

Comment: Вероятно, во внешнем флексе.

Comment: чучуть бы поточнее)))

Answer (score 0):

дайте для`menu-item` конкртеные размеры если у кaртины их нет и уберите    `flex-basis: calc((100% - 40px) / 3)` ``````

```
    .menu-list {
       width: 100%;
       display: flex;
       flex-direction: row;
       flex-wrap: wrap;
       gap: 20px;
     }

     .menu-item {
        height: 444px;
        width: 360px;
        list-style-type: none;
        border: none;
        padding: 24px;
     }
```

и думаю это лишнее, можно и без него`<article class="menu-card"></article>`

Comment: это карусель, по этому flex-basis. что бы не давать конкретные размеры стоит формула - calc((100% - 40px) / 3), если убрать <article class="menu-card"></article> - рассыпиться вся структура карточки